# context vs views

Tags: android

can anyone explain the difference between ***context and views*** and when do we go for context or view ? In most of the program I find either context or view being passed to certain methods , what is actual need of passing context or view to methods?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, because inside listeners we normally pass the views. But the function sometimes need context and beginners do not know how to get the context there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a strange question. View describes one element of your ui. It can have onClickListeners, properties and so on. But every view is created in some context, usually Activity's context.

Context as itself is something like environment your code is executed in. It has access to ui(if it is an activity), it can contain some global data(application context), and has access to the resources(all of the contexts). Also, context allows you to perform common android operations like broadcasting intents, start activities and services.

So, views should be passed when you want to do something with a particular view.
Context is passed when you need access to resources, global data or ui context, or launch other android components.

Answer (score 0):

We need to understand how `View` is constructed and what is `Context`.

`View` has three constructors, all of which use `Context` as an argument.

In `Activity,` if `view` is inflated programmatically as against in XML, `view` is inflated a `View` is by using `LayoutInflater`.

`LayoutInflater` takes `Context` as an argument and internally saves it in a class level field.

```
LayoutInfater layoutinflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

where "`this`" is the `Activity` instance.

When `inflater` inflates view i.e. :

`inflater.inflate(R.id.some_view, parent, null)`,

it is internally passing the saved `context` field to the constructor of `View`.

`View` always takes a `Context` as an argument and this is obvious because views live in some `Context` which is the `Activity`.

To answer your question, when `context` is needed to be passed to a method which itself is in `Activity`, you can write "`this`". If method is not in `Activity`, and you need to pass `Context`, then remember that `View` which has taken `Context` as a parameter, saves the object reference in a class level field. We can get this object reference by writing `view.getContext()`.