# what is the difference between views and context?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [context vs views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867588/context-vs-views)

Can anyone explain the difference between `Context` and `View` and when do we go for context or view? In most of the programs I find either context or view being passed to certain methods, what is the actual need of passing context or view to methods?

Thanks in advance