# Play song in android using android studio

Tags: android, playback

```
   Button playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)`enter code here`
        {
            MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shenkin);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }


    });
```

I am getting error on "this" as parameter to MediaPlayer.create
What should I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that scope, *this* refers to *new View.OnClickListener()*, but you want it to refer to your activity, or pass any other context. In that case, you should do:

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.shenkin); 
//Or whichever the name of the activity is
```

or something like

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shenkin);
```

Comment: Make sure to destroy this somewhere, or use the new sound pool depending on your use case, by your question media player sounds like the right choice

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Context` instead of `View`.

Read the post to know the difference and applications.
[context vs views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867588/context-vs-views)